# How to make org.apache.http.legacy work with ProGuard (azure mobile services)?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, android-6.0-marshmallow

The problem:

I'm using android mobile services, which relies on androidhttpclient.

Referencing org.apache.http.legacy resolves all the problems and the app runs just fine. However, with proguard on, I keep running into issues.

The problem plays out in two scenarios. If I keep the export checkbox checked (in jave build path), I get a 'Stub!' exception as expected (see discussion below)(see screenshot for which checkbox I'm talking about)

[image]

The runtime crash of type: "Stub!":

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stuffd/com.stuffd.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
   at org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage.(AbstractHttpMessage.java:7)
   at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase.(HttpRequestBase.java:7)
   at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.(HttpGet.java:8)
   at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceJsonTable.executeGetRecords(MobileServiceJsonTable.java:952)
   at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceJsonTable.executeUrlQuery(MobileServiceJsonTable.java:183)
   at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceJsonTable.execute(MobileServiceJsonTable.java:160)
   at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceTable.execute(MobileServiceTable.java:158)
   at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceTable.execute(MobileServiceTable.java:249)
   at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.query.ExecutableQuery.execute(ExecutableQuery.java:101)
```

If however, I keep the checkbox unchecked (as suggested - see discussion below), I get and AbstractMethodError exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.String org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase.getMethod()"
       at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.getMethod(AndroidHttpClient.java:283)
       at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:301)
```

proguard config used:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.**
-dontwarn com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.**
```

Has anyone else run into this and has figured it out?

Comment: Not sure what build tools you're using, but in general terms, don't link the stub library into your project.  Just build against it as a provided dependency.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede that's a thing, org.apache.http.legacy is not supposed to be a stub library... found another link indicating it's a classpath ordering problem (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/guRK1b8aEIQ), but moving things around does not seem to help.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be a stub library.  The whole Android SDK is a stub library.  Apache HTTP is still present on API 23 devices.  It was just moved out of the main stub library to further discourage its use.

Comment: Did you add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` to `build.gradle` (in the `android { ... }` section, say somewhere under `buildToolsVersion`)?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede you are right. all the stubs get replaced with real versions at runtime if actually present on the device. If they cannot be replaced, the stub remains. Question is then, why can't the stub be replaced? Not even on kitkat...

Comment: @fattire yes, builds and runs fine without proguard

Comment: Stubs do not get replaced.  The app should reference the stub classes and methods, but not include them in the apk.  If the implementations are not present at runtime, you would get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.  Seeing `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` indicates that the sub library has been compiled into the apk.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede you just made sense of the whole thing. this is exactly it. Will test. I think you can post your last comment as an answer pretty much verbatim :)

Answer (score 12):

Here's what I am using, allowing the OS to properly replace the stubbed methods at runtime.

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.codec.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.compatibility.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.**
```

It's all the stubbed packages provided by `org.apache.http.legacy.jar`.

Comment: thank you for contributing. still a stub/abstract runtime exception in my case...

Comment: This answer needs more attention -- it was the only solution that allowed me to compile SDK 23 using Eclipse with Proguard.

Comment: @mikejeep this is the only answer so far :) btw, even though mine compiled, I started getting runtime errors...

Comment: @rothschild86 There are many questions very similar to this posted on SO.. this is the only one that did the trick for me. All the others caused runtime errors for me.

Comment: @mikejeep Ah, i see :)

Comment: I can confirm the abnormal comes for `compileSdkVersion 23` and `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` but unable to find a fix. gradle build hang and ask me correct warning first, the warning is "there were 1 unresolved references to library class members". I tired your answer but unable to make proguard happy:(

Answer (score 0):

You're right not exporting the legacy apache lib. However it has to be located outside the `libs` folder and added to the Build Path (when using Eclipse). Otherwise it gets exported anyway with your `Android Private Libraries`.

I'm using GMS, Volley and AndroidHttpClient in my own communication classes.
Here's what I had to add to the proguard settings:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
-dontwarn com.myapp.communication.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```